# Cython compiled app requires python to be installed?

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc, cython

I have the following small program:

```
import urllib2,os
urls = ['http://stahlworks.com/dev/sfk/sfk.exe','http://stahlworks.com/dev/sfk/sfk.exe','http://stahlworks.com/dev/sfk/sfk.exe','http://stahlworks.com/dev/sfk/sfk.exe']
for fruit in urls:
url = fruit

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)
os.system('cls')
file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

I compiled it using Cython:

`python cython.py --embed -o hello.c h.py`

then I compiled it using gcc:

`gcc.exe -I"c:\python27\include" -L"c:\python27\libs" hello.c -ohello.exe -lpython27`

After I compile it it runs fine, until I try it on a computer without python/ python27 renamed to python27x then I get the following error:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.`

Is there any way I can get around this and build a truly standalone app?

Comment: yes you need... with Cython you only obtain one compiled module which is "importable" from Python

Answer (score 1):

I have used py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/) with reasonable success for windows applications. It packages up what's needed to run things in a nice way, including basic python libs.